# Why doesn't my XPath find my element on the page?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, xpath

I am trying to retrieve the content of the header and each chapter which is a repetitive structure as you can see below. For this am using Selenium and C#.

My attempt, using xpath, is this:

```
string xpath = "//article[@class='shared__reader__xx reader__container__content'][4]/div[@class='chapter xx'][1]"; // this should take the 5th chapter
var elem = GetElementBy(By.XPath(xpath), webDriver, 5);
```

where GetElementBy is based on the following method:

```
public static IWebElement GetElementBy(By by, IWebDriver webDriver, int seconds)
        {
            WebDriverWait webdriverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));  // e.g. 5
            IWebElement searchElement = webdriverWait.Until(x => x.FindElement(by));
            return searchElement;
        }
```

and the html is:

```
<div class="container__right">
    <article class="shared__reader__xx reader__container__content" lang="en">
        <div class="chapter xx" data-chapternumber="0" style="display: none;">
            <h1>Header ... </h1>
            <div class="chapter__content">
                <p>xx.</p>
                <p>xx</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>xx</li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter xx" data-chapternumber="1" style="display: block;">
            <h1>Header ... </h1>
            <div class="chapter__content">
                <p>xx.</p>
                <p>xx</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>xx</li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter xx" data-chapternumber="2" style="display: none;">
            <h1>Header ... </h1>
            <div class="chapter__content">
                <p>xx.</p>
                <p>xx</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>xx</li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
etc
```

I get the following error and I don't understand why:

> Timed out after 1 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//article[@class='shared__reader__xx
>   reader__container__content'][4]/div[@class='chapter xx'][1]"}

I should add that only 1 chapter is visible on the page, at once, in case that is a problem, but I think I was trying in my example to display a visible chapter, the 5th and last one, after parsing through all of them.

**Later edit:**
I changed string xpath to `"article[@class='shared__reader__xx reader__container__content'][4]/div[@class='chapter xx'][1]";` 
Same error. According to MSDN: `x[1]/y[2]` means: The second `<y>` child of the first `<x>`. And considering `chapterxx` element shows up once under each `reader__xx` element ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Even this didn't work: string xpath = "article[@class='shared__reader__xx reader__container__content'][4]/div[@class='chapter xx'][1]"; 
Same error. According to MSDN: x[1]/y[2] means The second <y> child of the first <x>. And considering chapterxx element shows up once under each reader__xx element ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add information about which browser are you using. Different browsers handle xpaths a bit differently :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your class selector for multi-class div is the thing that breaks it. 
Try

```
//div[contains(@class, 'shared__reader__xx') and contains(@class, 'reader__container__content')]
```

What is more, this line is trying to find 4th article element with class X and Y, but I think you only have one.

```
//article[@class='shared__reader__xx reader__container__content'][4]
```

I presume you are looking for something more like this:

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'shared__reader__xx') and contains(@class, 'reader__container__content')]/div[@class='chapter xx'][5]";
```

or

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'shared__reader__xx') and contains(@class, 'reader__container__content')]/div[@data-chapternumber='4']";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `[4]`?

Shouldn't it be: `string xpath = "//article[@class='shared__reader__xx reader__container__content'][1]/div[@class='chapter xx'][1]";`

Comment: This was already suggested in the answer from months ago.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of issues are generally faced by automation engineers while automating web applications. We used to discuss such issues in our [Automation strategy](https://blog.qasource.com/resources/8-tips-for-creating-the-ultimate-test-automation-strategy) meeting and found their solutions.

You can try the following locators to overcome such errors:

```
//article[@class='shared__reader__xxreader__container__content']/div[@class='chapter xx']
```

In case, there are multiple occurrences of '**shared__reader__xx reader__container__content'** class, you have to use the fourth occurrence. Then, you should try:

```
(//article[@class='shared__reader__xxreader__container__content'])[4]/div[@class='chapter xx']
```

Other locators, you can try:

```
 //article[@class='shared__reader__xxreader__container__content']/div[@data-chapternumber='0']



//article[contains(@class, 'shared__reader__xx') and contains(@class,'reader__container__content')]/div[@class='chapter xx']
```

Hope this information will help you. Thanks!!!!